# How to validate ARM Template using azure .net SDK or Fluent API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-rm-template, azure-sdk-.net

How to validate uploaded ARM Template using azure .net SDK or Fluent API ?
I want to validate my uploaded ARM template like azure portal do using azure .net SDK or Fluent API ?
For reference please see below image azure is showing message if ARM template not valid so same thing i want to implement using any .net API or REST API.

[image]

@Jim Below error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/arm-template-test/

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for reply but this is not relevant for me.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.deploymentsoperationsextensions.beginvalidateasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_DeploymentsOperationsExtensions_BeginValidateAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_IDeploymentsOperations_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Models_Deployment_System_Threading_CancellationToken_/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate your arm template, please refer to the following steps

1. Create a service principal and assign Contributor role to the sp

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp"
```

2. Install Package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent -Version 1.34.0
```

3. Code

```
 string clientId = "23****9c";
            string clientSecret = "?s****/k";
            string tenantDomain = "";
            string subscription = "";
            var creds= SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantDomain, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var restClient = RestClient.Configure()
                .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                .WithCredentials(creds)
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
                .Build();


            ResourceManagementClient managementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(restClient);
            managementClient.SubscriptionId = subscription;

            //Validates whether the specified template is syntactically correct and will be accepted by Azure Resource Manager..
            DeploymentValidateResultInner res = await managementClient.Deployments.ValidateAsync("<groupName>", "<deployName>", new DeploymentInner()
            {
                Location = "",
                Properties = new DeploymentProperties()
                {
                    ParametersLink = new ParametersLink("uri"),
                    TemplateLink = new TemplateLink("")
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine(res.Error.Message);

            // get changes that will be made by the deployment if executed at the scope of resource group
            WhatIfOperationResultInner res1 = await  managementClient.Deployments.WhatIfAsync("<groupName>", "<deployName>", new DeploymentWhatIf() { 
                  Location="",
                   Properties= new DeploymentWhatIfProperties() {
                       ParametersLink = new ParametersLink("uri"),
                       TemplateLink = new TemplateLink("")
                   }
            });

            foreach (var change in res1.Changes) {
               // 
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have ARM template and parameters file and I am passing directly both not with ParametersLink  , TemplateLink  but getting The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized.

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya Could you please provide the error message in detail?

Comment: The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value "{"$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json","contentVersion":"1.0.0.0","parameters":,"resources":[{"type":"Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules","apiVersion":"2017-04-26-preview","name":"[ipient":"[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationEmail')]"},"targetResourceId":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]"}}]}" to type 'Azure.Deployments.Templates.Schema.Template'. Path 'properties.template', line 4, position 1419.'.

Comment: I have updated my question and attached one more image so you will get error details from that.

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya please try to define template and parameter as Jobject. For more details, please refer to https://gist.github.com/ramnov/2c3fae176435e3b5bff19a905657c6a2

Comment: Thank u for the reply Yes It's working after define template and parameter as Jobject. But in the case of Invalid template If I am passing Valid template then  res.Error.Message throwing System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Can you please help me on this.

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya Regarding the error, I suggest you try to catch your request to check the error in detail.

Answer (score 3):

I like that the accepted answer adds the "what if" to validation. However, [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager) is deprecated, and it took me a bit to figure out a way to validate an ARM template using the replacement library: [Azure.ResourceManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager/).

Here's a code snippet that provides template validation using the new library (it doesn't include the what-if call):

```cs
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        var subscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
        var client = new ArmClient(credential, subscriptionId);

       var deploymentContent = new ArmDeploymentContent(new ArmDeploymentProperties(ArmDeploymentMode.Incremental)
                {
                    Template = BinaryData.FromString(templateContent),
                    Parameters = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new
                    {
                        hostingPlanName = new
                        {
                            value = hostingPlanName
                        },
                        webSiteName = new
                        {
                            value = webAppName
                        },
                        skuName = new
                        {
                            value = webSkuName
                        },
                        skuCapacity = new
                        {
                            value = webSkuCapacity
                        },
                    })
                });

        var resourceGroupId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(SubscriptionId!, resourceGroupName);
        // This ArmDeploymentResource resource may or may not exist, but it doesn't matter - it's just a placeholder for validation
        var deploymentResourceId = ArmDeploymentResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(resourceGroupId, deploymentName);
        var armDeployment = client.GetArmDeploymentResource(deploymentResourceId);

        var validateOperation = await armDeployment.ValidateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, toValidate, _cancellationToken);

        var validateResult = validateOperation.Value;
        if (validateResult.Error != null)
        {
            _logger.LogEndOperation(loggerOpKey, false, validateResult.Error.Message ?? "Validation errored");
            _logger.LogError(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(validateResult.Error, Formatting.Indented));
            return false;
        }

        // Log this if you want:
        string deploymentDetails = $"Deployment: {deploymentName} ProvisioningState:{validateResult.Properties.ProvisioningState}\n"
                                   + $"    started:{validateResult.Properties.Timestamp} duration:{validateResult.Properties.Duration}\n"
                                   + $"    correlationId:{validateResult.Properties.CorrelationId}\n"
                                   + $"    outputs:{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(validateResult.Properties.Outputs)}";
        bool succeeded = validateResult.Properties.ProvisioningState == "Succeeded";
        return succeeded;
```